# How to get the second numeric value from string using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below format of String and I just want to get the second numeric value from the below string.

**Input (output of jq):**

```
"Test Result: 21 tests failing out of a total of 5,670 tests."
```

**Expected Output:**

```
5,670
```

I used the below command but it returned all numeric value can't fetch the second one.

```
echo "$getTotalCount" | jq '.healthReport[0].description' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
```

**Getting below output:**

```
215670
```

Is it possible to get the values like index based [0] (Result = 21) will fetch first numeric value and [1] (Result = 5670) will fetch second numeric value like that?

Comment: Yes....Its output of jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk with a custom Field Separator to extract the number:

```
<<<"$getTotalCount" jq -r '.healthReport[0].description' | awk -F'[^0-9,]+' '{ print $3 }'
```

- Pass the contents of the variable to `jq` using `<<<` (if your shell doesn't support this, you can use `echo` and `|` as you were)
- Use `jq -r` to output the "raw" value, removing the quotes.
- Use `-F'[^0-9,]+'` to set the field separator to anything that is not a digit (0-9) or a comma
- Print the third field, which is the number that you want.

This is what the fields end up looking like to awk:

```
Test Result: 21 tests failing out of a total of 5,670 tests.
^ $1 (empty)
^-----------^ field separator
             ^^ $2
               ^-------------------------------^ field separator
                                                ^---^ $3
```

To save the output to a variable, just use:

```
num_tests=$(<<<"$getTotalCount" jq -r '.healthReport[0].description' | awk -F'[^0-9,]+' '{ print $3 }')
```

Comment: Is it possible to store the value in variable?

Comment: Its working. I can assign to variable by using yours solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the spaces in the original message.

```
echo "$getTotalCount" | jq '.healthReport[0].description' | sed -e 's/^.* of //' -e 's/ tests.*//' -e 's/[^0-9]//g'
```

Which will strip anything up to the ' of ', anything after 'tests', and keep only digits.

Side note:
jq has lot of string built-in function. You might be able to complete the full extraction in jq using regular expression.